# How do I suppress scientific notation while controlling significant figures in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to print numbers that range across 8 orders of magnitude. I would like to print them with a fixed number of sig figs but not in scientific notation.

Toy program:

```
n = 123456.0
while n > 0.01:
    print(<format statement>)
    n = n/10
```

**Desired output** of this program:

```
120000
12000
1200
120
12
1.2
0.12
0.012
```

I've found a couple solutions that aren't quite right.

Option 1)  `f'{n:.2f'}` gives output:

```
123456.00
12345.60
1234.56
123.46
12.35
1.23
0.12
0.01
```

It's not in scientific notation, but number of sig figs is all wrong.

Option 2)  `f'{n:.2'}` gives output:

```
1.2e+05
1.2e+04
1.2e+03
1.2e+02
1.2e+01
1.2
0.12
0.012
```

Sig figs are correct, but large numbers get printed in scientific notation, rather than padding zeros. My numbers aren't big enough for scientific notation, so readability suffers. I could hack a method to do this, but I'm hoping there's a magic format string to do this for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is first `pip` installing `sigfig`.
Then you can use this code:

```py
from sigfig import round
n = 123456.0
while n > 0.01:
    # rounds to two significant figures
    print(round(n, sigfigs=2))
    n = n/10
```

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully that package is in the deployed environment

Answer (score 0):

I did end up writing a method for this, for anyone for whom `sigfig` is unavailable

```
def num_fmt(n: float, sf: int = 3) -> str:
    """
    Returns number as a formatted string with specified number of significant figures
    :param n: number to format
    :param sf: number of sig figs in output
    """
    r = f'{n:.{sf}}'  # use existing formatter to get to right number of sig figs
    if 'e' in r:
        # for big numbers, strip scientific notation and pad with zeros
        exp = int(r[-2:])
        r = r[0]+r[2:-4] + '0' * (exp-sf+2)
    return r
```

Comment: WARNING: This fails in some cases:

num_fmt(323.2939331, 2)   ===>   '3200'